# Need a BI Dashboard to use for SaaS Application

Tags: analytics, ssas, business-intelligence, dashboard, web-analytics

I've developed a SaaS application in .net 4.0 and SQL 2008 for my customers and I need to display their data in a dashboard for them to view. This dashboard should be embedded into my application so that its all on our system. So far I've seen 2 options:

1 Build the dashboard and reporting functionality from scratch. Use a system like fusioncharts for the charts and graphs. Take each analytic component and determine which will be automatically generated from the use of the software and which data must be inputted by management to produce the eventual graphs/charts, most likely the revenue goals sections, sales pipeline etc.

2 Use a third party API and embed their system with mine. So far I've found these companies that have what I'm looking for

a.GoodData

b.PivotLink

c.Birst

d.splunk storm

My Question is which path should I take. It seems the first one is more expensive upfront and longer to implement, while the second one there are monthly plans that I can jump on and the deployment should be around 30-60 days.

I need the management and high level sales staff to be able to view their data and also input what they need to generate their reports.

If anyone has worked with these companies or has implemented an analytical dashboard for their application I would really like to hear your opinions and suggestions on how to move forward.

Thanks

Comment: I've done similar things, with similar toolsets, and found that the either technical deficiencies, the tight integration required, or licensing charges precluded the use of complete third-party solutions - we needed something that could work with IE6, iOs, and could be printed server-side exported to a printable image.  We ended up making the dashboard from scratch, using Ext4's chart component + the MS Chart API, but if we could have found something off-the-shelf we'd be happy.

Answer (score 0):

Initially we had a java based desktop dashboard solution. It took us 3 yrs to build a web based dashboard completely from scratch. Dashboards are not just pretty charts, you need designing interface, data interface/engine, charting engines and all need to talk across different intersection points. Plus you need to think about login/security and role based access control system.

If you are looking to throw quick charts and pre-built reports then just go with web charting libraries and there are plenty of options now including d3js. This will be economical but will take little time to stitch all together and cumbersome to maintain

If you have say around $2k - $3k to spend then you can invest in a formal dashboard application just like ours. This is a pricey but speedier to implement.

Hope this helps.

Nilesh

PS:

[InfoCaptor Dashboard](http://www.infocaptor.com) is web based and built on top of PHP. You can integrate the dashboards in any web application and it provides OEM and white label licensing so that may suit your purpose

Answer (score 0):

You can also look at [RazorFlow PHP](http://razorflow.com) which is a PHP framework for building interactive dashboards which also work on mobile devices.

You can also embed dashboards, and interact with them from another web application by means of a jQuery plugin, so it will work with other web frameworks.

(Disclosure: I am the developer of this product and I am posting only because I feel it's relavant)